# Will wind shear influence a sail's center of effort?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Wind shear going up a mast on a sailboat can be significant when it comes to the performance of the boat in light air conditions. A boat with a higher mast has access to higher wind, albeit the higher you go up the mast the less sail area.

If the wind speed is the same up the height of the mast I would expect the center of effort to be the same regardless of wind speed changes. The question is, if the wind shear is present and the wind speed is increasing the higher up the mast you go does the center of effort also move vertically? If yes, how does one calculate for this?

In this model the Center of Effort (CE) is going to be the the point of the sail, typically a triangle though parallelogram sails are becoming more common, where the force vector comes from when the wind travels over the sail. See: https://www.dependablepickup.com/how-do-you-find-the-center-of-effort-of-a-sail/

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! Can you edit your question to add a definition of "center of effort", for those who aren't familiar with sailing terms?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert added, let me know if it isn't sufficient and I can try to add more

Comment: How could wind shear not affect the CE? Of course it does! But so does the change in shape (camber,twist, etc.) due to changes in loading that continually occur.

Comment: Even without any changes in shape or wind shear, changes in angle of attack also affect the CE. Modeling it as constant is an extremely rough approximation.

Comment: @D.Halsey I know it does, but I would like to prove it through calculation.

Comment: It doesn't need to be proven, it's trivially true. Your problem is how to calculate it accurately and that is quite difficult. 3-D lifting surface theories assume potential flow and are of limited use with sheared onset flows like yours. You probably need a full Navier-Stokes calculation (although you will find some counterexamples - Lissaman, etc.)

Comment: @D.Halsey thank you, that's good feedback.

Comment: Note also that the apparent wind angle will also be twisted - giving the sail a larger angle of attack at the head than at the foot. So accounting for the speed variation alone isn't enough.

Comment: @D.Halsey does this mean a boat clause hauled can sail at a higher angle if heeled towards windward?

Comment: @D.Halsey btw, if there is a chance we could chat outside of SO I feel like you're someone I've been looking for :)